# Tiles and Live Tiles in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-8, live-tile

Is there any difference between Tile and Live tiles in windows 8 phone.
or we can use both interchangeably.
I googled it but not finds any satisfy results.

Comment: and it will be helpful if any one tell the implementation difference of these two.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends (not actually, but let's assume it this time) on the template for the tile you choose. If the template exists for both WP8 and W8, then the code allowing it to actually do anything looks the same if you utilize C/C++, C# or Visual basic. BUT, most of the templates (XML) does have some differences so most of them will need som opt-ins by you to work on different platforms. So, the short answer is no, they do not work interchangeably and the long one is yes, if you modify the parser (which you can, but should not do!).

Alex